# How can I create a bool column for a view based on the result of a statement?

Tags: postgresql, view, exists

I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
  id        SERIAL        NOT NULL,
  name      TEXT          NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id        SERIAL        NOT NULL,
  group     INT           NOT NULL,
  name      TEXT          NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (group)
    REFERENCES groups(id),
  UNIQUE (group),
  UNIQUE (name)
);
```

I want to create a view that includes a boolean column stating whether or not a group has any users based on the has many / belongs to relationship of the two tables above. If it's easier, I'd even be fine with an integer column stating how many users a group has in it. How can I do this in my view?

```
CREATE VIEW group_info AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    g.name        AS name,
    ????          AS empty
  FROM groups AS g
  JOIN users AS u
    ON (g.id = u.group)
;
```

I've looked into using `BOOL_OR` and/or `COUNT` to help with testing the existence of a group ID in the users table, but I'm not seeing how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"a boolean column stating whether or not a group has any users"*

Use [**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS):

```
CREATE VIEW group_info AS
SELECT g.name, NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users u WHERE u.group = g.id) AS empty
FROM   groups g;
```

This returns **1 row per group**, no matter whether there are users or not - not one row per user like you had, but probably didn't want - so we don't need `DISTINCT`.

It's [largely irrelevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710153/what-is-easier-to-read-in-exists-subqueries) whether you write `SELECT 1` or `SELECT *` or `SELECT 'foo'` in the `EXISTS` subquery. Only the bare existence of at least one row matters.

#### With number of users

```
CREATE VIEW group_info AS
SELECT g.name, count(u.group) AS ct_users
FROM   groups     g
LEFT   JOIN users u ON u.group = g.id
GROUP  BY g.name;
```

`LEFT JOIN` is crucial to retain groups without users.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Can you help me understand how to include this as part of my view I'm trying to create?

Comment: For completeness, how would I get the number of users rather than just the existence of users?

Comment: @Bryan: That's a different query, typically more expensive with big tables and/or many users per group.

Comment: Thanks Erwin... any idea why I'm getting an error saying "g.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause when I try to create the view?

Comment: @Bryan: Oh, because my query was missing the last line. Sorry, fixed.