# How can I aggregate multiple results from another table using something like BOOL_AND?

Tags: postgresql, view

I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id        SERIAL        NOT NULL,
  name      TEXT          NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
  id        SERIAL        NOT NULL,
  name      TEXT          NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE associations (
  user      INT           NOT NULL,
  group     INT           NOT NULL,
  admin     BOOLEAN       NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  PRIMARY KEY (user, group),
  FOREIGN KEY (user)
    REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (group)
    REFERENCES groups(id)
);
```

Similar to another question I posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86548/how-can-i-create-a-bool-column-for-a-view-based-on-the-result-of-a-statement), how can I compare the result of multiple rows from another table and aggregate them in a view, perhaps using something like `BOOL_AND`?

```
CREATE VIEW user_info AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    u.id              AS id,
    u.name            AS name,
    EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM associations AS a
      WHERE (u.id = a.user AND a.admin = true)
    )                 AS is_admin,
    BOOL_AND(???)     AS is_complete_admin
  FROM users AS u
;
```

Here, I'm wanting the `is_complete_admin` to be true if **every** row in `associations` for a particular user has `admin = true`.

Again, I *think* `BOOL_AND` is an option here, but I'm just not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    u.id,
    u.name,
    bool_or (a.admin) as is_admin,
    bool_and (a.admin) as is_complete_admin
from
    users u
    inner join
    associations a on u.id = a.user
group by u.id, u.name
```

Comment: This seems way too easy... but it worked perfectly!